# Laravel display latest comment of a post

Tags: laravel, controller, forum

I have a table of threads, and on the index page I want to display the latest comment of the thread. So far I have selected the latest comment and try to display it on the page, but it only displays the latest comment overall, not the latest for the specific post[image]

So my ThreadsController looks like this right now, selecting all the comments and displaying the latest one first.

```
 public function index()
    {
        $threads = Thread::latest()->paginate(10);
        $latestComment = Comment::latest()->first();
        return view('threads.index', compact('threads', 'latestComment'));
    }
```

Thread model

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }
```

Comment Model

```
public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function thread()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Thread::class);
    }

    public function commentable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

So how do I select the latest comment from the specific thread and display it on the index?

Edit:

Controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $threads = Thread::latest()->with('comments')->paginate(10);

        return view('threads.index', compact('threads'));
    }
```

Index blade:

```
@foreach($threads as $thread)
    {{ $thread->latestComment->user->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comments table migration

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('body');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('commentable_id');
            $table->string('commentable_type');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: You need to create a [`relationship`](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch/episodes/29) between a `Thread` and `Comment`s.

Comment: @Unflux Yeah they have a relationship in my models that have been working fine, but this issue I don't really know how to solve

Comment: Can you provide the code which shows your relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your relationship between a `Thread` and `Comment` correctly, but you're not making use of that relationship in the `index` function of your `ThreadsController`. You're just grabbing the latest 10 `Threads` and the most recent `Comment`, but not the comment related to your `Thread`.

What you're wanting is to get all your `Threads` and pass them to your view with their latest `Comment`.

You can use [`eager loading`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to attach your `Comment` relationships to your models.

```
Thread::latest()->with('comments')->paginate(10);
```

That will grab your 10 latest `Threads` along with their `Comments`. So in your view you could do something like:

```
@foreach ($threads as $thread)
    {{ $thread->comments()->latest('id')->first()->comment }}
@endforeach
```

Whilst this works, it's a bit verbose. So what you can do is piggy back off your `comments` function to return just the most recent `Comment` as a relationship.

```
class Thread extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }

    public function latestComment()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Comment::class, 'commentable')->latest('id');
    }
}
```

This gives you shorter method for accessing the latest `Comment` for a `Thread`.

So going back to your scenario;

In your `ThreadsController.php`

```
public function index()
{
  $threads = Thread::latest()->with('latestComment')->paginate(10);
  return view('threads.index', compact('threads'));
}
```

Then in your `index.blade.php` file

```
@foreach ($threads as $thread)
  {{-- Access whatever properties you have on your comment --}}
  {{ $thread->latestComment->id }} 
@endforeach
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. Can you update your question with new information?

Comment: Updated the image, there's basically nothing that limits it to only display one comment, and it still displays all comments and not the comments associated with that specific thread

Comment: Can you also provide your updated `index` method and `blade view` code?

Comment: @OskarB Make sure you have the `latestComments` relationship on your `Thread` model and in your controller replace `with('comments')` with `with('latestComment')`.

Comment: That was a mistake, forgot to change back when I tried both of the versions you wrote. The output is still the same when I use the correct with()

Comment: If you output the `id` for the `latestComment` does it work?

Comment: Still the same output, all the ID's for the last comments

Comment: Something is foobar, double check the `latestComment` relationship on the `Thread`.

Comment: Okay, the solution was to just remove the foreach in the index.blade. Thanks for  guiding me!

Comment: Confused, but glad you got there!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a relation between tread and comment.
And then in blade you cam do something like this:
$thread->comments->latest()->first()

Comment: I can't use latest method in the blade page, it has to be something done in the controller I think

Comment: Then you can format your data directly in your controller and return exactly the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
Comment::all()->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get()
```

Comment: That will still only output all the comments

Comment: try this: Comment::all()->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get()->first()